# unable to install wine i am getting this error

Tags: wine

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score -1):

From your question, it seems that you are trying to install 32-bit Wine on 64-bit Ubuntu or 64-bit Wine on 32-bit Ubuntu.

Apparently you are using the terminal.

Please try the Ubuntu Software Center to check if it helps you install Wine.

As for me, I installed Wine on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit using Ubuntu Software Center and I faced no problems.

Comment: i am also installing from ubuntu software center and then it is showing this error in detail

Comment: There is a question on askubuntu pertaining to unmet dependencies

http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Please check the above link